# Better way to create a contingency table with pandas for film genres from a Film DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

From a public dataset available on film rating I created a contingency table as follow.

Honestly I don't like all these "for-loops" I think the quality of the code can be definitely improved in a more pythonic way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

movies_df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uomodellamansarda/GentleIntroduction2MLandDataScience/main/L10/movies%20(1).csv")

# Getting series of lists by applying split operation.
movies_df.genres = movies_df.genres.str.split('|')

# Getting distinct genre types for generating columns of genre type.
genre_columns = list(set([j for i in movies_df['genres'].tolist() for j in i]))

# Iterating over every list to create and fill values into columns.
for j in genre_columns:
    movies_df[j] = 0

for i in range(movies_df.shape[0]):
    for j in genre_columns:
        if(j in movies_df['genres'].iloc[i]):
            movies_df.loc[i,j] = 1

print(movies_df)
```

And this is the output after running my code
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're working with`0`, `1` and `NaN` instead of `True`, `False` and `None`?

Comment: No reason in particular, generally as for `.get_dummies()` method they transform in 0,1 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html?highlight=get%20dummies#pandas.get_dummies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas isn't very good at this - it's not very vectorisable. But you can still avoid some of your loops.

"Pythonic" somewhat secondary here, and instead you're looking for "Pandas-idiomatic".

You can replace your nested list/set/list comprehension with a call to `reduce(set.union)` if you've cast your genres column to `set` using `apply`. I tried `agg` but it didn't work.

You can avoid `loc` and `iloc` if you use another `apply` per column value using set membership.

### Suggested

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

movies_df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uomodellamansarda"
    "/GentleIntroduction2MLandDataScience/main/L10/movies%20(1).csv")

movies_df.genres = movies_df.genres.str.split('|').apply(set)
genre_columns = reduce(set.union, movies_df.genres)

for genre in genre_columns:
    movies_df[genre] = movies_df.genres.apply(lambda s: genre in s)

print(movies_df)
```